# Creating a random string with only "A's" and "2's" in python

Tags: python, random

I wanted to create random 16bytes long strings that only include "A's" and "2's" to decrypt my AES-encrypted ciphertext. How do I achieve this with python?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should at least be able to do it via a naive for loop generating 16 random numbers either 0 or 1 and map those to A and 2.

Comment: If you have ciphertext that's encrypted then you need the *key* to decrypt it, not random strings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah you are right, I just realized I am stupid oops.
I could limit the key area to only "A" and "2" and wanted to bruteforce it. I dont know why i suddenly thought I had to create random strings containing those two characters haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cryptographically-secure randomness

```
from random import SystemRandom

sr = SystemRandom()
l = (b"A", b"2")
result = b"".join(l[sr.randrange(0, 2)] for i in range(16))

print(result)
```

For modeling or simulations (or most use cases), you can just use `randrange()` without `SystemRandom`.

Example Output

```
b'2A22AA2222AAA222'
```